# input field with "xxx-xxxxxxx-yy" need to be validated

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am trying with a validation for an number format and the number should be automatically replaced in the character while typing.

The format is: xxx-xxxxxxx-yy AND in another field "xx-xx-xx-xxx-xx"

My Code:

```
$('#id_number').on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
        $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
        var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Numeric characters only.</span>');
        }
    });
```

I have come up till allowing numeric. But replacing the character with number while user type.. becomes difficult.

Can some one help me. Is there any regex?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#id_number').on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
  $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  //$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
  var numericReg = /^(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{7})?(?:-\d{2})?|\d{2}(?:(?:-\d{2}){0,2})?(?:-\d{3})?(-\d{2})?)$/gm;
  if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
   $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Numeric characters only, and pattern should match either "xxx-xxxxxxx-yy" or "xx-xx-xx-xxx-xx".</span>');
  }
 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inp-wrap">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_number" name="id_number" maxlength="20" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split the code into 2 events: `blur` and `keyup/keypress`.

Regular expression for `blur` is validating *the whole input*:

```
^(?:\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{2}|\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2}-\d{3}-\d{2})$)
```

Regular expression for `keyup/keypress` events that allow the user to input any digits and "hyphen-digits" groups:

```
^(?!.*-{2})\d+(?:-(?:\d+)?)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.. another approach.. and works perfectly! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#id_number').on("keyup blur", function(event) {
  $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var length = inputVal.length;
        var letters = /[^0-9-]/gm;
  
        if(letters.test(inputVal)) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''));
    }
        var buff = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        inputVal = inputVal+buff;
        inputVal = inputVal.substr(0,15);
  var numericReg = /^([x\d]{3}[x-][x\d]{7}[x-][x\d]{3})$|^(([x\d]{2}[x-]){3}[x\d]{3}[x-][x\d]{2})$/gm;
  if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).val(inputVal.substr(0,length-1))
   $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Numeric characters only, and pattern should match either "xxx-xxxxxxx-yy" or "xx-xx-xx-xxx-xx".</span>');
  }
 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inp-wrap">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_number" name="id_number" maxlength="20" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex would work `/^\d{1,3}-\d{0,7}-\d{0,2}|^\d{1,3}-\d{0,7}|^\d{1,3}/`. Additionally, I would use a timeout so you only check and replace characters once the user has stopped typing

```js
$(function() {
    var timeOut = 0;
    $("#test").on('keyup blur', function() {
         var e =$(this);
        // cancel looking, the user typed another character
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        // set a timeout, when user doesn't type another key
        // within the time set, the function is called
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
   stopptedTyping(e);
  }, 300); // change time as needed
    });

});

function stopptedTyping(e){      
  e.val( e.val().match(/^\d{1,3}-\d{0,7}-\d{0,2}|^\d{1,3}-\d{0,7}|^\d{1,3}/));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```